# In Rust, is there a way to make function accept two types without a trait?

Tags: rust

I am pretty new to Rust. My question is more theoretical. The problem is this.

I have a state machine (to parse XML via [quick-xml crate](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/latest/quick_xml/) but this is not important for this question) whose transition logic is controlled by a `match` expression. A lot of branches of the expression have additional match guards. Most of those match guards are pretty identical and look like:

```rust
Event::Start(bs: BytesStart) if bs.local_name().as_ref() == b"any-tag" => NextState,
// and
Event::End(be: BytesEnd) if be.local_name().as_ref() == b"any-tag" => SomeOtherState,
```

To clean up the code I would like to move that equality comparison to a separate function, like:

```rust
fn tag_is(tag: &<either BytesStart or BytesEnd>, assertion: &str) -> bool {
    tag.local_name().as_ref() == assertion.as_bytes()
}
// and use it
Event::Start(bs: BytesStart) if tag_is(&bs, "any-tag") => NextState,
```

[BytesStart](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/latest/src/quick_xml/events/mod.rs.html#69) and [BytesEnd](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/latest/src/quick_xml/events/mod.rs.html#589) are different structs/types, and both have their own `.local_name()` methods. If the `.local_name()` was defined in some trait (`TraitWithLocalName`) and implemented for both, then I would write a generic like:

```rust
fn tag_is(tag: &impl TraitWithLocalName, assertion: &str) -> bool {...}
```

So, the question is, how to deal with that kind of situation - when a function might accept various types of an argument, which don't share the same trait?

Comment: As far as I know you cannot do that. You could however don't make a function, but instead write a macro that will expand to this check.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own trait that has this function and implement it for both `BytesStart` and `BytesEnd`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use an enum and implement `From` for both types. If one would want to avoid a trait at all costs. But I agree that a custom trait is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with a function. If you really wanted to, you could try doing it with a macro. I would strongly prefer defining my own trait to doing things this way, but it's up to you.

```rust
macro_rules! tag_is {
    ($x: expr, $assertion: expr) => {{
        let assertion: &str = $assertion; // type checking - makes sure assertion is a str.
        let s: &[u8] = $x.local_name().as_ref();
        s == assertion.as_bytes()
    }} 
}

struct BytesStart;

impl BytesStart {
    fn local_name(&self) -> &str {
        "hello"
    }
}

struct BytesEnd;

impl BytesEnd {
    fn local_name(&self) -> &[u8] {
        b"any-tag"
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    println!("{}", tag_is!(BytesStart, "any-tag")); // false
    println!("{}", tag_is!(BytesEnd, "any-tag")); // true
}
```